# SMTP server local send mail php

Tags: php, smtp, local, hmail-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mail(): SMTP server response: 550 The address is not valid error on hmailserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495509/mail-smtp-server-response-550-the-address-is-not-valid-error-on-hmailserver)

I would like test my class senderMail.php.

For to have, a smtp server, I use hMailServer. I have created a domaine, I have created a account, and now I configure SMTP settings.

hMailServer would like a configuration "SMTP RELAYER". I test with the information:
smtp.gmail.com on port 587 and I enter my identifier too.

When, I have tested this with my class senderMail.php I have this error:

> > SMTP server response: 550 The address is not valid

Where come my error ? It's from SMTP RELAYER or a other config ?

Comment: have you tried swiftmailer.? instead of ssl use tsl..

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try it to send it directly from localhost.

1. Go to your `php.ini` file and change `SMTP = localhost to SMTP = aspmx.l.google.com` and uncomment `sendmail_from` and put in **your sending gmail address**.
2. In php, test it with `mail("youremail]@gmail.com", "subject", "body");`

**Note:** This only works when sending email to google hosted email addresses.

**OR**

try above if its not work use [**swiftmailer**](http://swiftmailer.org/) its php mail sending library which also allow to send mail through SMTP its really helpful during development.

Comment: the config it doesn't work. Can I change the port too (in php.ini) ?

Comment: no don't change port....on which mail address are u sending mail...?

Comment: I sending and a receive my mail with the same address. [myAddress]@gmail.com

Comment: try checking spam if its there...i am too much sure that first solution work because i am using it...and yah don't forget to restart php apache services to make it in action...do RESTART if u didn't...

Comment: no spam, I use WAMP it's the probleme ? I have always this error "SMTP server response: 550 The address is not valid."

Comment: can you please paste your all php code with html form.?

Comment: mail("[My_eMail]@gmail.com", "Title", "textContent");
just this code, no form for this moment.

Comment: Now, after restart all services I have this error:
Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;aspmx.l.google.com&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

Comment: Can u please show me ur php.ini file code which u edited...

Comment: [mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = aspmx.l.google.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = MY_ACCOUNT@gmail.com