# Can't send email from localhost using gmail id

Tags: php, email, gmail

I'm using windows 7 and xampp 1.8(mercury mail is on) and trying to send email from localhost using gmail id. but its not working. heres my email.php :

```
<?php
$to="receiver.email@gmail.com";
$subject='the subject';
$message="dfdgh";
$headers='From:my.email@gmail.com'."\r\n".'Host:ssl://smtp.gmail.com'."\r\n".'Port:465'."\r\n".'Username:my.email@gmail.com'."\r\n".'Password:mypassword'."\r\n".'Reply-To:my.email@gmail.com'."\r\n".'X-Mailer:PHP/'.phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

and heres my localhost php smtp configuration that I changed

```
;SMTP = localhost
;smtp_port = 25
SMTP =ssl://smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 465
; For Win32 only.
;http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost
ssl://smtp.gmail.com
sendmail_from = my.email@gmail.com
```

I got no error message after I execute the code but didn't receive any email.

What wrong did I do ?

-Thanks.

Comment: there is 1 extra line (2nd last line) : `ssl://smtp.gmail.com` and you don't need to add Host, Port, Password in email header

Comment: did you check xampp/mailoutput?

Comment: @Kaii , sorry,I don't understand, could you plz make it clear ?

Comment: try to go your your xampp/mailoutput folder to check whether the mail is stuck there or in mercury/Queue folder

Comment: mailoutput folder is empty

Comment: Check your spam/junk folder on the receiving end.

Comment: checked,no email there.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail SMTP has stopped working on `465` and `SSL` so use below configuration.

Before it was worked perfectly but now its working on below config.

```
SMTP =tls://smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 587
tls://smtp.gmail.com
```

Use `587` `SMTP_PORT` and use `TLS`.

and if its not working then replace `SMTP = tls` line to `SMTP = aspmx.l.google.com`

Comment: @user1844626 have you restarted your services..?

Comment: @user1844626 take a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518902/smtp-server-local-send-mail-php/14519745#14519745

Answer (score 0):

debug it first in

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

try to write down a condition to see if mail is sending

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
echo 'Success';
}
else{
echo 'Failed';
}
```