# how to send contact form to mail from website

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm having contact form in my website, when user filled the form it should send the form with user content to my mail. I have tried this it show blank page.

Here is my form:

```
<form id="contact_form" action="mail.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Name:</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="name" />
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-md-3 control-label">E-mail:</label>
         <div class="col-md-5">
             <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" />
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Mobile Number:</label>
         <div class="col-md-5">
             <input type="email" class="form-control" name="mob" />
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Requirement</label>
         <div class="col-md-5">
             <textarea class="form-control" name="mess" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">GET A QUOTE</button>
          </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And PHP mailer: I have tried this, when executed it shown blank

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $mob = $_POST['mob'];
    $mess = $_POST['mess'];
    $subject = 'Message from website';
    $to = 'mailus@pebibytetech.in';
    $headers="From: {$email}\r\nReply-To: {$email}";
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    $success = "Thank you! You're email has been sent.";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[PHPSimpleMail](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/files/downloads/PHPMailer_5.2.0.zip)

Simple PHP Mailer is Better then inbuilt PHP Function. 
look at [this link](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) for more info.

Also you need to use input type according to your need.
like if you want to get Email then use

```
For Email: <input type="email" name="email">
For Phone: <input type="tel" name="phonenumber">
For name: <input type="text" name="FirstName">
```

Don't use email type in all input fields.

Answer (score 0):

You are not displaying anything while the `mail()` is success.

```
   if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
         echo $success = "Thank you! You're email has been sent.";
    else
         echo "Failed!!";
```

Also you have not defined `$message`. Change `$mess` to `$message`.

Comment: but mail doesn't arrives I'm using in wamp

Comment: Could you try sending it to a gmail address?

Comment: yes, I'm sending to gmail, still shows blank page again.

Comment: Try `<button name='submit'>` in your form.

Comment: Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 550 The address is not valid.

Comment: Checkout [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495509/mail-smtp-server-response-550-the-address-is-not-valid-error-on-hmailserver)

Comment: If you are using wamp follow [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830673/wamp-send-mail-using-smtp-localhost)

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` form attribute. Study below link. It is very useful. [Contact Form Data Email Link](http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php)

Comment: Are you sure he needs that? Enlighten yourself [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)

Comment: Ohh, I am really very sorry for wrong answer....@a3ey

Comment: The world will not be destroyed by those who do evil but by those who watch and do nothing. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your Form(Replace this to your code)

```
<form action="#" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Name:</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">E-mail:</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Mobile Number:</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="mob" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Requirement</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="mess" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="GET A QUOTE">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

then below the form, add this php code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $mob = $_POST['mob'];
        $mess = $_POST['mess'];

        if(empty($name)||empty($email)||empty($mob))
        {
            ?>
            <script>
                alert('Name, Email, Mobile is empty');
            </script>
        <?php
        }
        else
        {
            // Method 01 (Normal method)
            $to = 'mailus@pebibytetech.in';
            $subject = 'Message from website';

            $headers="From:".$email;

            $message = 'Customer Name :'.$name;
            $message .= '<br>Customer Mobile :'.$mob;
            $message .= '<br>Customer Email :'.$email;
            $message .= '<br>Customer Message :'.$mess;

            $mail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
            if(isset($mail))
            {
                ?>
                <script>
                    alert('Mail Sent');
                </script>
            <?php
            }
            else
            {

                ?>
                <script>
                    alert('Mail Sending Failed');
                </script>
            <?php
            }

            //method 02, Using table

            $to = 'mailus@pebibytetech.in';
            $subject = 'Message from website';

            $headers="From:".$email;

            $message = '<html><body>';
            $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border: 1px solid #eee; width: 850px" cellpadding="10">';
            $message .= "<tr><td width='25%'><strong>Name</strong> </td><td width='75%'>".strip_tags($_POST['name'])."</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email</strong> </td><td>" .strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Mobile</strong> </td><td>" .strip_tags($_POST['mob']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Message</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['mess']). "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "</table>";
            $message .= "</body></html>";

            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
            $headers .="From:".$email;//can add  $headers="Cc:".$email;

            $mail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

            if(isset($mail))
            {
                ?>
                <script>
                    alert('Mail Sent');
                </script>
            <?php
            }
            else
            {

                ?>
                <script>
                    alert('Mail Sending Failed');
                </script>
            <?php
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Did  you check the answer??