# PHP Mail 550 Error

Tags: php, email

I received a task from a client to edit a form on his website. The form used the mail() function of PHP. I changed the 'to' address (first parameter) to his email address.

As soon as I changed the email address I started receiving the following error.

[image]

With a GMail address or another domain address (mine, for example) it worked and I received the email in a couple of minutes.

Code snippets are pointless as it is a simple php mail function.

He owns the server, he's hosting the website in house so I believe it may be a misconfiguration problem.

Comment: This error means that the sender is trying to send an email to an address which he is not allowed to send.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495509/mail-smtp-server-response-550-the-address-is-not-valid-error-on-hmailserver

Comment: the mail server logs may tell you a little more