# Showing error - Sending HTML email using PHP

Tags: php, email

I have written below code getting error while executing.

```
<?php
        $to = "somebody@example.com";
        $subject = "My subject";
        $txt = "Hello world!";
        $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: somebodyelse@example.com";
        $retval = mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
         if( $retval == true ) {
            echo "Message sent successfully...";
         }else {
            echo "Message could not be sent...";
         }
      ?>
```

URL : http://www.casaplaya.co.za/test-email.php

> Message could not be sent... PHP Warning:
>   mail(E:\IIS\LogFiles\PHP\php53mail.log): failed to open stream:
>   Permission denied in F:\domains\casaplaya.co.za\wwwroot\test-email.php
>   on line 18 PHP Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 550 No such user
>   here in F:\domains\casaplaya.co.za\wwwroot\test-email.php on line 18

I am unable to figure out the the issue. It will be great if anybody help me to find out the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add the correct user to header?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mail(): SMTP server response: 550 The address is not valid error on hmailserver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495509/mail-smtp-server-response-550-the-address-is-not-valid-error-on-hmailserver)