# php mail() error depends on domain to which the message is sent

Tags: php, email

First of all, let me say that I use HostGator to host my web site.  They have very poor technical support and have been of absolutely no help in resolving this issue.  I'm trying to create php code that allows site visitors to register for a periodic update.  It's a simple form where they enter their first name and email address to which they want the updates sent.  When they click on the submit button, a welcome email is sent to them and an SQL database is updated.  I'd like to use the phpMailer() function but HostGator is not being helpful in making this 3rd party software available to me.  As a result, I'm using the php mail() function.  My problem is that if I try to send an email to either of my registered domains, the messages go through just fine.  However, if I try to send the same message to any domain other than my registered domains, including my yahoo and gmail accounts, I get an error (Warning: mail() [function mail] SMTP server response: 550

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mail(): SMTP server response: 550 The address is not valid error on hmailserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495509/mail-smtp-server-response-550-the-address-is-not-valid-error-on-hmailserver)

Answer (score 0):

You can use phpmailer without any external help by using composer.

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer